# Retrieve specific row from a table in another HTML file - Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I was wondering if somebody could help me out with this one.  I have 2 html pages, page1.html and page2.html.  page1.html has an text box, a button, and 3 labels.  page2.html has a table called mytable that has this data.

```
Number  Color   Shape
1       Red     Square
2       Blue    Circle
3       Orange  Triangle
```

On page1.html I am trying to input a number in the textbox, after hitting the button and will bring back the corresponding row into the 3 labels.  So if I enter in 2, the 3 labels will show 2, Blue, Circle.  Any ideas? I researched all over and the closest I got was this code below.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

page1.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<title>Acknowledgement</title>
</head>

<body>
<script>

var value1="value1";
var value2="value2";
var queryString = "?para1=" + value1 + "&para2=" + value2;
window.location.href = "page2.html" + queryString;

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

page2.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Acknowledgement</title>
</head>
<body>
<h4>These are the data from page1.html.</h4>

<script>

var queryString = decodeURIComponent(window.location.search);
queryString = queryString.substring(1);
var queries = queryString.split("&");
for (var i = 0; i < queries.length; i++)
{
  document.write(queries[i] + "<br>");
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Short answer: don't? If it's real data, it comes from somewhere. As _that_ thing for the same data (e.g. using an API call). And if it's toy data, "this is not how you do this kind of thing". You don't scrape other pages to build "this page", you fetch data from data endpoints and then do whatever you need to do with that data.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Mike.  My first thought to accomplish this was to use a csv file as my data.  I found a lot of good info on how to get the full csv file into my page, but the csv file has 10k rows, which is why I only want a specific row.  I don't have a web server and my html page is a pretty basic page.  Can I accomplish this using a csv file?  Thanks again.

Comment: remember that you're on the web, so compare what you're loading to what else you're loading: 10k rows of plain text data is vastly smaller to transfer (thanks to server size gzip for transport) than having one or more larger JPEG images on your page. Just load it in, see what the performance is: I'd bet it's perfectly acceptable. And remember: browsers can cache data. If you ask for the same data file on any other page, but on the same URL, the browser will load up the cached version and not even spend any real time on it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use localstorage or

Assign value in page 1 before navigation
 window.myobj={val1:"val1",val2:"val2"}

Get data on page 2
var mydata=window.myobj;
console.log(mydata.val1);